# Find index of second array and get record based on that index

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set flag to true of matching records of myArray whose field value matches with cars1 variable.

Now cars1 and cars2 records have 1 to 1 relationship with each other that means t1 of cars1 points to abc of cars2 respectively.

While matching myarray with Cars1 if match found then I want to note index of cars1 and based on that index I would like to get record from cars2 and assign to array2 at that index position.

For eg: t1 of myArray and t1 of cars1 is matching so index of t1 is 0 so based on this index get 0th index record from cars2 and assign to array2 at 0th index.for t3 pqr will be at 2nd position in array2

**Expected output in array2 :**

```
array2 = ["abc" ,undefined, "pqr",undefined,"lmn" ];
```

But here i am not getting how to note index of matching record of Cars1 and assign to array2 at that index position.

```js
var myArray = [
    {field: 't1', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't2', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't3', flag: false},
    {field: 't4', flag: false},
    {field: 't5', flag: false}
];

var cars1 = ["t1", "t3","t5"]; 

var cars2 = ["abc" ,"pqr", "lmn" ];

var array2 =[];

myArray.forEach(car => car.flag = cars1.indexOf(car.field) > -1);

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the repeated-search way (fine for small data sets), and the build-a-map way (for quite large data sets).

#### The Repeated Search Way

You can do that with `map` on `myArray`, looking up `car.field` in `cars1`: and then if found returning that entry from `cars2`:

```
const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1.indexOf(car.field);
    if (index === -1) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});
```

ES5 and earlier:

```
var array2 = myArray.map(function(car) {
    var index = cars1.indexOf(car.field);
    if (index === -1) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});
```

Note that this uses `Array.prototype.map` with side-effects (setting the `flag`). A purist would say `map` should never have side-effects.

Example:

```js
const myArray = [
    {field: 't1', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't2', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't3', flag: false},
    {field: 't4', flag: false},
    {field: 't5', flag: false}
];

const cars1 = ["t1", "t3","t5"]; 

const cars2 = ["abc", "pqr", "lmn"];

const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1.indexOf(car.field);
    if (index === -1) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});

console.log(array2);
console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that that repeatedly does a linear search on `cars1`, which is absolutely fine for the sample data and most use cases. If `cars1` were in the hundreds of thousands of entries, you might want to build a map that maps value to index so you get more efficient lookup.

#### The Build a Map Way

Building the map (in an object, since the keys are strings and they're crazy-efficient):

```
const cars1Map = Object.create(null);
cars1.forEach((entry, index) => {
  cars1Map[entry] = index;
});
```

ES5 and earlier (but for < ES5, you'll need a polyfill for `Object.create`):

```
var cars1Map = Object.create(null);
cars1.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  cars1Map[entry] = index;
});
```

Using it:

```
const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1Map[car.field];
    if (index === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});
```

ES5 and earlier:

```
var array2 = myArray.map(function(car) {
    var index = cars1Map[car.field];
    if (index === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});
```

```js
const myArray = [
    {field: 't1', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't2', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't3', flag: false},
    {field: 't4', flag: false},
    {field: 't5', flag: false}
];

const cars1 = ["t1", "t3","t5"]; 

const cars2 = ["abc", "pqr", "lmn"];

const cars1Map = Object.create(null);
cars1.forEach((entry, index) => {
  cars1Map[entry] = index;
});

const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1Map[car.field];
    if (index === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});

console.log(array2);
console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or a purist might say that in ES2015+, you should use `Map` (and you'd definitely want `Map` if your keys weren't strings):

Building it:

```
const cars1Map = new Map();
cars1.forEach((entry, index) => {
  cars1Map.set(entry, index);
});
```

Using it:

```
const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1Map.get(car.field)
    if (index === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});
```

(And again, you can add a guard if you don't like relying on looking up `undefined` in the map.)

```js
const myArray = [
    {field: 't1', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't2', flag: false}, 
    {field: 't3', flag: false},
    {field: 't4', flag: false},
    {field: 't5', flag: false}
];

const cars1 = ["t1", "t3","t5"]; 

const cars2 = ["abc", "pqr", "lmn"];

const cars1Map = new Map();
cars1.forEach((entry, index) => {
  cars1Map.set(entry, index);
});

const array2 = myArray.map(car => {
    const index = cars1Map.get(car.field)
    if (index === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }
    car.flag = true;
    return cars2[index];
});

console.log(array2);
console.log(myArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*